# usb barcode scanner

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to develop an application that can read bar codes. Is there a 'scanner' that works with dot net?

I found this http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/barcode-reader but I'm looking for a scanner that I can program against using dot net.

The project is for a non profit that has a library and they are wanting a better way of tracking their books. So I'm thinking they can print out the barcodes that the scanner could read and if I could program against the scanner I could write an application that stores the info / other.

Comment: as far as I know all scaners send keys, as if you pressed them in your keyboard, it is really easy, the info you get when you scan is just a string, you can use it everywhere, excel, notepad, or inside your app. it sends enter key too, after your string so all you have to do is code for enter key press

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

For your scenario, just buy a $50 POS scanner that connects via USB. It will provide any barcode input through keyboard emulation. **You will not need to interact with the scanner and you can develop your application without a device - all you need is a `TextBox` which is focused when you scan something**.

**Long answer:**

While Ednumd Covington's answer is mostly correct for scanners that support the USB HID profile (they tell the OS they are a keyboard and you don't even interact with the scanner at all - to you it's just like as if the user had entered the contents of the barcode by hand), there's another option.

More sophisticated devices (esp. by Datalogic or Motorola) also support an USB to COM emulation. Once correctly configured, they create a virtual COM port which you can read from as if it were a real serial device. This allows you to have *far more control* about what's actually happening.

This, for example, allows you to also use the scanner in non-ui applications like Windows Services. Also, some other disadvantages of the USB keyboard emulation approach are gone when you use serial emulation.

Just one scenario: Say your application is meant to assign items to boxes. You have a certain barcode format for items and one for boxes. For example, the item barcode always has this format: `I12345-111`, the barcode for boxes has this: `B00.11.22`.

Using the USB keyboard emulation you need to make sure that the cursor is within the item text box if an item is scanned or in the box text box if a box is scanned.

Using COM emulation, you can first decide whether an item was scanned or a box was scanned and assign the input to the correct text box. The user has less ways to do things wrong.

Also, it is a common misconception that barcodes only contain numbers! This applies only to EAN/UPC barcodes. Most other barcode types can contain letters, too.

Answer (score 1):

A barcode scanner only converts the barcode into a string (usually of numbers) and so a barcode scanner that works on a pc will work with .net.